# Float в бинарный код и обратно

Tags: float, php, javascript

Через РНР генерирую числа и с помошью pack преобразовываю их в бинарный код для последующей записи в файл.
Потом, через JavaScript, получаю этот файл и вытаскиваю оттуда массив float чисел, используя формулу:

```
Math.pow(-1,S) * Math.pow(2,E-Math.pow(2,(b-1))+1) * (1+M/Math.pow(2,n))
```

где S - первый бит; E - целая часть; M - остаток мантиссы;
b и n - количество бит под целую часть и мантиссу.

В результате в РНР получил следующее число - `782.662037`. 
Получаю файл через JS и "достаю" оттуда мое число, получилось: `783.9998168945312`.
И так с многими числами, а точнее с определенными интервалами, например, число `1035,*\*\*\*` получается больше, чем `2000,\*\*\*\*`.

В чем причина таких непредсказуемых результатов?

Comment: Чем какой-нибудь json не угодил?

Comment: @Ni55aN, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Etki, нехорошо получится, ведь файлов очень много, и в json представлении они будут весить уже не ~3 кб, а 8 кб.

Answer (score 1):

Прчина в том, что в стандарте IEEE 754 на число выделяется ровно 8 байт(=64 бита), не больше и не меньше. Отсюда и неверные вычисления javascript. http://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: как тогда быть с теми float, под которые выделено 32 бита?